# How to enable wireless on Ubuntu Server 18.04 via CLI?

Tags: networking, server, package-management, iwlwifi, wpa

I cannot get wpasupplicant, wireless-tools, and also lib, iwconfig (Iget ifconfig) to operate on my Server 18.04 install.

I have Windows 10 on laptop. External HD with 18.04 Desktop and 18.04 Server. 
Wireless works fine on the other two OS, but not non-GUI Server CLI.
I can’t install packages with no wireless.

I AM ABLE to go to https://packages.ubuntu.com/ and get any package I want via search.

I AM ABLE to save these *.deb files on the /home drive of the server partition, reboot into Server, run some sudo dpkg and sudo apt-get install commands (all CLI). Some of it appears to install some but I get a lot of errors too. My guess is it’s trying to reach out over wireless for some of the packages parts but no wireless enabled? I’m not sure what a good order of package installs to enable wireless would be.

It seems that this issue would have a “recipe” for a good method and order of installation of certain packages to enable your intel 7265 network controller (wlo1), if not a basic recipe for installing packages for wireless without wireless or Ethernet access.

Remember, I can surf the net with Desktop and download packages to a server directory.

Right now every package seems to be looking for missing parts. I'm hunting with a blindfold. I'm using WPA encryption.

These are *.deb packages and *.iso files I have access to in server:

[image: Screenshot showing downloaded iso and deb files]

@chili555 I can't use iwconfig because I can't install wireless-tools without internet? I can't seem to install packages from my dual accessible drive shown in the picture above? I also get the following with `sudo cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`:

[image: photo of attempt to install wireless-tools]

Thank you for the welcome.

`ipaddr` show gives me this:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e4:42:a6:a0:42:95 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: Ubuntu server 18.04 and later use netplan, not /etc/network/interfaces. Do you have a wireless interface? Please edit your question to show the result of these terminal commands: `iwconfig` and also: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: edited above^. added your requested commands. No dice.

Comment: May I also see: `ip addr show` I hope that will give me enough information to suggest a netplan file with which you can connect.

Comment: 1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e4:42:a6:a0:42:95 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

Comment: you found a way?

Answer (score 23):

Let's amend your netplan file. From the terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
```

Amend the file to read:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  wifis:
    wlo1:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: true
      access-points:
        "network_ssid_name":
          password: "**********"
```

Of course, substitue your network name and password. Note that both are enclosed in quotation marks ".

Netplan is quite strict about indentation and spacing; proofread carefully. Next, do:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

Reboot and tell us if you connected:

```
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

If you get ping returns, you are all set.

Reference: https://netplan.io/examples

Comment: FINALLY got indentation correct! $sudo netplan generate, $sudo netplan apply both give no errors. Reboot, ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com --- Temporary failure in name resolution

Comment: That may suggest that you are not actually connected. How about: `ping -c3 8.8.8.8` Are there any clues in: `dmesg | grep wlo` ?

Comment: This worked for me - I'm not sure why it was downvoted. Thanks @chili555

Comment: same issue as dubfactor. Using Ubuntu 20.04. `ping -c3 8.8.8.8` returns network is unreachable, the second command does not return anything.

Comment: @Adam I suggest that you start your own new question and include a redacted version of your netlan yaml file as well as the result of: `iwconfig`

Comment: I am currently trying out the setting specified in `Connecting to a WPA Personal wireless network`  from https://netplan.io/examples. If it fails, I will ask a new question. Thanks.

Comment: This was a life saver for me! Two things to add thou:
1. Provide exact interface name instead of 'wlo1'. I found mine during the boot and it was like 'wlx1cbfce123'
2. Install `wpasupplicant` library, along with its two own dependencies: `libnl-route-3-200` and `libpcsclite1`. Once you install those deps and provide netplan config, suggested by @chili555, all works fine after reboot. Cheers !