# Cannot connect to wifi ubuntu server 20.04 fresh installation

Tags: networking, server, 20.04

I installed a fresh ubuntu server 20.04. Then I am unable to connect to my home internet wifi. I followed this [How to enable wireless on Ubuntu Server 18.04 via CLI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1105069/how-to-enable-wireless-on-ubuntu-server-18-04-via-cli/1107570#1107570), but isn't helping either. I have attached screenshot of the terminal outputs, please let me know if this is enough.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The screenshots show following outputs:

1. Ubuntu version to confirm (Pic 1)
2. Filename of default yaml file and its content after I changed (Pic 1)
3. output of `ip addr show`. I used the wlp8s0 in the yaml file (Pic 1)
4. output of netplan generate (Pic 2)
5. output of netplan apply (Pic 3)
6. error outputs when pinging (Pic 4)

What could be going wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: On your first picture you have 2 network interfaces and they all `down` you can read it from the output, to bring it up `ip link set enp7s0 up` for example

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  Turns out that for some crazy reason, wpa_supplicant is NOT installed by default on Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS!  Search your syslog for messages similar to the following:

```
Failed at step EXEC spawning /sbin/wpa_supplicant: No such file or directory
```

But of course, simply typing `apt install wpa_supplicant` doesn't work.  That is because the package is called wpasupplicant in APT land. Try, `apt install wpasupplicant`.

Once wpa_supplicant is installed, your system should work fine.  You can grep your syslog to see what is happening with the wifi connection.  It is pretty verbose.  Just enter this:

```
grep wpa /var/log/syslog
```

Hope this helps.