# Ubuntu Server on Raspberry Pi 5 is not connecting to the internet

Tags: networking, server, ethernet, raspberrypi, 23.10

Ubuntu Server  on Raspberry Pi 5 is not connecting to the internet.

Images of the errors:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried reinstalling it at least 5 times: [Ubuntu server on Pi won’t connect to Internet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1479120/ubuntu-server-on-pi-won-t-connect-to-internet)

more insight hope this helps

KRAYTONIAN — 03/24/2024 8:34 PM
@randomUser1
Ubuntu Server 23.10 on Raspberry Pi 5 wlan0 is domrant but I want to get rid of the continous brcmfmac: erros

additional info
bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/netplan.io/+bug/2041727

forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=367466
Image
Image
Image

helpfuluser1 — 03/24/2024 9:09 PM
Despite retaining the same Infineon CYW43455 802.11ac + BT5/BLE combo chip as the Pi4 (which had issues back then, too),  it looks like the Raspberry Pi foundation has it communicating with the new Broadcom BCM2712 SoC via an updated SDIO interface in order to leverage DDR50 mode for faster throughput, and that could be causing the reported problems  (you're far from the only person reporting this).

Best I can tell,  the new RP1-C0  I/O chip is out of the loop on this one as far as possible causes.

TL;DR,  the only people who can diagnose the root cause and fix this will be Broadcom, Canonical since you're trying to use Ubuntu Server 23.10 with it, and the Raspberry Pi Foundation.

We lack the necessary magic wands to fix this.

KRAYTONIAN — Today at 9:24 AM
thanks

helpfuluser1 — Today at 9:30 AM
Wish I had a better answer, but it's affecting not just Ubuntu, but also Arch users, so there's something going on.   I didn't encounter this with Ubuntu _*desktop*  22.04.whatever-version  back in January (same with the ARM64 version of Kali for it),   but that's not the same as 23.10, so it could be kernel changes/driver breaking.
It's wild that it's spamming an error about the broadcom driver, even though you've disabled that interface.
I have so many other things to work on right now (I've got like a month long project to try and crank out ASAP)  so won't have any time in trying to see if I could replicate it,  and if so, fumble my way into some kernel update/driver recompile that "fixes" it.

KRAYTONIAN — Today at 9:32 AM
@HelpfulUser1 you are super quick thanks for your insights can I show you some stuff and you let me know what you think?
helpfuluser1 — Today at 9:33 AM
It'l probably end up being like a hotfix from Canonical or a blogpost + fix from the Raspberry Pi folks.
No prob!

HelpfulUser1— Today at 9:34 AM
Depends on what the "stuff" is,  and how much of it I need to look through, since I'm scrambling to get this project done for Name1,  as well as the usual course support
If it's something I need to stop what I'm doing for a couple of hours, then I may need to say "Gimme a couple hours, or a day or two,  and maybe then I can look at it"
(I'm not joking when I saw it'll take a solid month minimum to get this done, and that's if I can sprint through it all that fast)
KRAYTONIAN — Today at 9:35 AM
https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=367466

This is my post on ask ubuntu:
[Ubuntu Server on Raspberry Pi 5 is not connecting to the internet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1508490/ubuntu-server-on-raspberry-pi-5-is-not-connecting-to-the-internet)

forums.rpi:
https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=2206266#p2206266
Ask Ubuntu
Ubuntu Server on Raspberry Pi 5 is not connecting to the internet
Ubuntu Server on Raspberry Pi 5 is not connecting to the internet.
Images of the errors:
I tried reinstalling it at least 5 times: Ubuntu server on Pi won’t connect to Internet
Image

KRAYTONIAN — Today at 9:36 AM
I did not realize you are part of the staff.
thanks you for any help you could provide

helpfuluser1— Today at 9:42 AM
I had previously looked through the Arch thread and Raspberry Pi threads you posted, as well as looked at your screenshots (same one you posted on the ubuntu forums),   and did a little digging on my own,  which is how I discovered that folks with Pi4's  were also encountering similar issues with Ubuntu/Arch and that driver,   and that the Pi4 and Pi5's share the exact same Infineon chip,  despite having differeing Broadcom SoCs (the main "CPU"  or "Application Processor" as The RPI foundaton calls it).  The thing is, they eventually fixed it for the Pi4s, but it looks like a recent issue with Pi5.

I also checked the pcb traces, datasheet, schematics, and even a X-ray some dude took of his Pi5,   and was able to rule out that new RP1  I/O controller chip as being the culprit, since  1)  It's not affecting all distros and versions  and 2)  The new broadcom SoC bypasses that RP1-C0 chip to directly connect to the infineon combo chip.

I still think it's something in the kernel that's changed between the last stable  Ubuntu, Kali, and "Rapsbian/PiOS releases I tried in January  vs   Ubuntu 23.10 and Arch in March 2024 (which is when I noticed the most recent complaints that mentioned that broadcom driver and "Pi5"),   to be honest.
I don't think that even IF I had tons of free time to try and scour every forum post and github/gitlab issue ticket out there,  that I'd necessarily be able to find a solution any faster than Canonical, Broadcom, and RPi foundation,  to be honest.
I'm just befuddled that it's spamming that message, even if you disable that built-in wlan0 interface
If you've got a spare SD card, you could try imaging an older Ubuntu release, swap out the SD card, power your Pi5 back up, and see if the same thing occurs.

helpfuluser1 — Today at 9:50 AM
(That would be my first move:  confirm whether an older Ubuntu release is unaffected, as well as newer Kali and PiOS releases to see if they exhibit the same behavior.  After that, it would be an attempt to upgrade the kernel,  as well as checking any relevant forums and github/gitlab repo issue tickets. )

Comment: Thanks for the edit here are some helpful links I could not make out what i need to do.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/netplan.io/+bug/2041727
https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=367466